# Do not show Firebase Cloud Functions default log lines

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `express` as my server for Firebase Cloud Functions.
There are many endpoints in my server, and they are all managed by express routers.
Then I pass the express instance to firebase and it works great.

My problem is that every time an endpoint gets called, the following log lines appear in console:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "app"
i  functions: Finished "app" in ~5s
```

While this is nice to know how much time did it take for my endpoint to finish, these log lines are meaningless to me, since they always only mention "app". No helpful information.

This is legit and fits my configuration, but I would like to **get rid of those log lines**. I couldn't find any mention to them on the official documentation nor in the module source code.

Do you have an idea how can I control Cloud Functions default logging?

---

My `index.js` file looks similar to this:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello world!");
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "."
  }
}
```

I run the server locally with `firebase serve --only functions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs in the Firebase console are not configurable other than what you immediately see on that page.  If you want a more customized logging experience, you should look into [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) and [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) to create more a more sophisticated view of your logs.

Answer (score 0):

how did you form your url to call the function?

if `http://localhost:5001/yourapp/us-central1/` is your host, then your URL should be `http://localhost:5001/yourapp/us-central1/api/` for the `helloworld` function or `http://localhost:5001/yourapp/us-central1/api/api/users` for your users function.

check carefully whether you have formed the URL correctly